# Erro 400 ao criar InputStreamReader para URL com espaços ou acentos

Tags: java, json

Olá, estou com um problema quando uso o InputStreamReader para ler algumas URL's que contenham espaços ou acentos. O que acontece é que estou lendo uma URL que contém um JSON (Uma das APIs do League of Legends). Não tenho ideia do que está acontecendo, quando uso algum Nickname sem acentos ou espaços eu consigo ler com sucesso o JSON, caso contrário a URL retorna 400 (de acordo com o StackTrace) que é "Bad request" para a API.

Percebam que, quando uso um nick sem espaços/acentos ele funciona corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ambas imagens acima o código funcionou corretamente.

Agora quando utilizo nicks com espaços e acentos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei também inserir o nick com "%20" no lugar dos espaços em branco, mas sem sucesso. Caso eu copie a URL como está na "URL lida" e colar no navegador eu consigo acessar o JSON perfeitamente (com "%20" também).

Código que estou utilizando para a leitura:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://" + server + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + server + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + name + "?api_key=" + key);
    System.out.println("# URL acessada: " + url);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String json = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("# Lido: " + json);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando a seguinte linha:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection()).getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

e na URL antes...

```
"https://" + server + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + server + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + name + "?api_key=" + key
```

...ficou:

```
"https://" + server + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + server + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + URLEncoder.encode(name.replaceAll(" ", ""), "UTF-8") + "?api_key=" + key
```

Fontes:
[Fonte 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349703/server-returned-http-response-code-400), [Fonte 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)